# Delete records in multiple table at once for example delete records table name like 'John%' ,where user_name='doe'

Tags: mysql, sql-delete

I would like to delete  records in different tables which table name starts with 'customer' and customer_id is 'X'

Comment: Note: IT should be a single query ;)

Comment: Don't think that is possible. However you can have foreign key constraints where you can propagate deletes

Comment: Of course you don't really have separate tables for each customer. That would be ridiculous.

Comment: I just gave an example.It is not a real table name